# How to test proportion against 1 - null hypothesis: H0: p=1

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion, extreme-value, normal-approximation

**My research question:**
I have a data set with good observations and bad observations and have to estimate if all observations are good in the population with 99% confidence.

**My suggested method:**
My idea was to test whether the proportion of good observations (let it be p) is significantly smaller than 1. That is,

H0: p0 = 1, H1: p < 1

**My problem:**
However, if I use p0 = 1 the variance will obviously be 0 (p0*(1-p0)/n). Further, normal approximation is questionable. But approaching this matter with a binomial(n=., p=1) is not working either.

**My ideas for solutions**
Do I use p0=0.9999 to approximate 1? Or do I test against 1 but use a maximum possible standard error of sqrt(0.5*(1-0.5)/n)? However, sampling very, very expensive, so this might be an overkill.

Comment: Surely a single observation of "bad" suffices to definitively reject the null. Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify whether you in fact *have* a data-set with good and bad observations, as you say; or whether you've yet to collect data, which would explain why you complain about sampling's being expensive & suggest you need to be thinking about power and sample size.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Comment: @Scortchi thanks for the reply. I indeed haven't sampled yet. But I am certain there will be 1 or more bad observations. I expect above 90% and below 100% to be good observations.